# how to escape unusual/uniq characters from expect scripts?

Tags: linux, tcl, ksh, expect

in expect script I can set any command or character to run it on remote machine
but the sad thing is that expect cant send the same character as they defined in the expect script

for example

I want to run this line from expect script in order to change IP address from **10.10.10.10**
to **1.1.1.1**

```
    expect #  {send "perl -i -pe 's/\Q10.10.10.10\E/1.1.1.1/' /etc/hosts\r"}
```

but when I run the expect screen actually I see this line runing on the console:

```
   [root@localhost ~]# perl -i -pe 's/Q10.10.10.10E/1.1.1.1/' /etc/hosts
```

pay attention that the backslash before Q and before E was Disappeared

so I wonder hoW to escape those characters from expect script?

so expect will run the same line on the console as following

```
   [root@localhost ~]# perl -i -pe 's/\Q10.10.10.10\E/1.1.1.1/' /etc/hosts
```

- REMARK set a backslash "\" before backslash doesn’t help!!!

my script:

```
 #!/bin/ksh

 #
  expect=`cat << EOF
  set timeout -1
  spawn  ssh  192.9.200.10 
   expect {
             ")?"   { send "yes\r"  ; exp_continue  }

             word:  {send secret1\r}
          }
   expect #  {send "perl -i -pe 's/\\Q10.10.10.10\\E/1.1.1.1/' /etc/hosts\r"}
   expect #    {send exit\r}
   expect eof
   EOF`


    expect -c  "$expect"
```

RESULTS ( after I run my script: )

```
  spawn ssh 192.9.200.10 
  root@'192.9.200.10 s password: 
  Last login: Sun Aug  4 22:46:53 2013 from 192.9.200.10 
  [root@localhost ~]# perl -i -pe 's/Q10.10.10.10E/1.1.1.1/' /etc/hosts
      [root@localhost ~]# exit
      logout

      Connection to 192.9.200.10  closed.
```

Comment: Same question asked in 3 places: [unix&linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85494/4667),
[superuser](http://superuser.com/q/627819/4714),
[stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18044771/7552)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using different Tcl quotes will work

```
expect #  {
    # send text verbatim here
    send {perl -i -pe 's/\Q10.10.10.10\E/1.1.1.1/' /etc/hosts}
    # interpret backslash sequence as carriage return here
    send "\r"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either escape it with `\` or enclose the whole thing in `{}`

```
expect #  {send "perl -i -pe 's/\\Q10.10.10.10\\E/1.1.1.1/' /etc/hosts\r"}
```

(Enclosing the entire thing with `{}` would send `\r` as this 2 characters, not as line terminator, so not appropriate here.)

See the the [manual page about the Tcl Syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

And an other note:
You could do the same thing with Tcl, as long as you don't send the commands over SSH

Comment: I already try it ( I put "\" before the first "\" , and this not help

Comment: please try it - I edit my quastion with my script you can try it on your machine and see that "\" before "\" not help ,

Comment: Well. Bash replaces ``\\`` with ``\``, which is not what you want. Try ``\\\\``. Ugly, but necessary.